# Why My Spring Boot APP not coming up once I deploy it in Heroku

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku

I'm trying to upload my spring boot app to Heroku by using 
Heroku plugin deploy.
Once I run this command : `mvn heroku:deploy`
Build finish successfully but app didn't get up anymore!.

Note: I don't have the Procfile because I'm using the Heroku Plugin.
With using `Procfile`, I still getting the same error as well! ( this need to push the code to git and push code to Heroku , different way ... but getting the same error as well!.)

I get this error in logs:

```
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466787+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1322) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466788+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466789+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1215) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466791+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1093) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466792+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466794+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.<init>(DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java:77) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466795+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a0096270.<init>(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466796+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466798+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466799+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466800+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466802+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466803+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466804+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:275) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466806+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466807+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466809+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466810+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466811+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.466815+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467047+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467049+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467050+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467055+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467057+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467058+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467059+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467060+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467062+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467063+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467064+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467066+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:514) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467067+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467068+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1198) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467069+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorBeansComposite.get(HealthIndicatorBeansComposite.java:46) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467071+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration.healthEndpoint(HealthEndpointConfiguration.java:38) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467072+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4dc5c6cd.CGLIB$healthEndpoint$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467082+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4dc5c6cd.healthEndpoint(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467081+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467080+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467084+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467078+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4dc5c6cd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d5ba48f1.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467105+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467199+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467201+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467203+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467204+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467205+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467206+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467208+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467209+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467210+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467211+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467213+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467214+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467216+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467217+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBean(EndpointDiscoverer.java:143) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467218+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBeans(EndpointDiscoverer.java:132) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467219+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:122) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467221+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:116) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467222+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.servletEndpointRegistrar(ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.java:75) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467223+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e75968c5.CGLIB$servletEndpointRegistrar$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467225+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e75968c5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b10d5d4d.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467226+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467231+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467419+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e75968c5.servletEndpointRegistrar(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467422+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467423+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467424+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467427+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467426+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467428+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467430+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467432+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467431+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467434+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467435+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467436+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467438+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467439+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467440+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467441+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:214) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467443+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:91) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467444+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:80) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467445+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:250) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467446+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:237) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467448+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467449+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467452+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467468+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467470+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467471+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467473+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467474+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467476+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_181-heroku]
2018-09-29T14:47:09.467477+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-29T14:47:09.632814+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-09-29T14:47:09.616643+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-09-29T14:47:11.329023+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/UserManagementsMS/v1/login/UserInfo" host=springtest2018.herokuapp.com request_id=38b49b15-b1a4-4c24-99b3-0a09c045b75c fwd="89.138.131.176" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-09-29T14:47:11.924356+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=springtest2018.herokuapp.com request_id=502fb75e-91b7-4926-b5c4-0cdf1fc6cfe1 fwd="89.138.131.176" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-09-29T14:51:27.771084+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=springtest2018.herokuapp.com request_id=007000a2-22d6-4d45-b818-3a37dcbf5129 fwd="89.138.131.176" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
^COsaids-MacBook-Pro:user-managment-ms-v1 osaidwattad$ mvn heroku:deploy
```

My POM.XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ims.ms</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-managment-ms-v1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>user-managment-ms-v1</name>
    <description>user-managment-ms-v1</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <full-artifact-name>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</full-artifact-name>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- this changes for Heroku connection , building and connection to DB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jscience</groupId>
            <artifactId>jscience</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end of Heroku configurations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>springtest2018</appName>
                    <includeTarget>false</includeTarget>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${basedir}/${full-artifact-name}</include>
                    </includes>
                    <jdkVersion>1.8</jdkVersion>
                    <processTypes>
                        <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -jar ${full-artifact-name}</web>
                    </processTypes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: You're missing the main part of the error message. Leave `heroku logs -t` and restart the app in another terminal

Comment: or run `heroku logs -n 2000`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding buildpack section with heroku/jvm to your plugin configuration:

```
<buildpacks>
    <buildpack>heroku/jvm</buildpack>
</buildpacks>
```

And set server.port to $PORT heroku env variable like in example below:

```
<processTypes>
    <web>java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar ${full-artifact-name}</web>
</processTypes>
```

After all changes it should look something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <appName>springtest2018</appName>
        <includeTarget>false</includeTarget>
        <buildpacks>
            <buildpack>heroku/jvm</buildpack>
        </buildpacks>
        <includes>
            <include>${basedir}/${full-artifact-name}</include>
        </includes>
        <jdkVersion>1.8</jdkVersion>
        <processTypes>
            <web>java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar ${full-artifact-name}</web>
        </processTypes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```